# Как в springboot security перенаправить авторизованного юзера на кастомный URL?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

есть простая корневая домашняя страничка, которая видна всем. Но тот, кто прошел регистрацию или успешно авторизуется, то нужно заредиректить его на следующий URL: HOMEURL/profile/{userId}, понятно, что где userId это id пользователя. Также если не авторизованный просто в URL вводит следующий адрес с указанием */profile/{userId}, также спринг должен просить пройти авторизацию. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как создать редирект на URl профиля заавторизованного юзера с указанием его ID в конце URL.

например:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/registration", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String registration(@ModelAttribute("userForm") User userForm, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {
    userValidator.validate(userForm, bindingResult);

    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "registration";
    }

    userService.save(userForm);

    securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

    return "redirect:/profile/{userId}";
}
```

Из выше сказанного, понятно что надо как то в return вместо /profile/{userId} вставить реальный ID авторизованного юзера.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Самый простой и естественный способ - поменять в ссылке идентификатор на имя:

```
return "redirect:/profile/" + userForm.getUsername();
```

Либо исправить метод `autologin` так, чтобы он возвращал идентификатор в случае успеха:

```
Long id = securityService.autologin(userForm.getUsername(), userForm.getPasswordConfirm());

return "redirect:/profile/" + id.toString();
```